When Éowyn secretly followed Théoden as Dernhelm, who was in charge of the Rohirrim?
Théoden appointed Éowyn as his steward when he went riding off to Gondor with Éomer. Then Éowyn disguised herself as a man and followed.
Did Éowyn leave the remaining Rohirrim leaderless when she left? That sounds highly irresponsible, but seems to be true as far as I can tell. I can see nothing in the books that indicates otherwise, though by "books" I mean The Hobbit, The Lord of the Rings, and The Silmarillion.

Éowyn's departure left Rohan without a representative of the royal family but not without leadership.
Per the Tolkien Gateway (citing "Unfinished Tales") Erkenbrand,  was left in charge of the Rohirrim defenders, even when Théoden believed that Eowyn would also be there.

Erkenbrand did not come to Minas Tirith to fight in the Battle of the
Pelennor Fields. King Théoden gave him the command of the forces that
were left behind to defend Rohan because of Erkenbrand's dignity and
authority.

Since Éowyn was Théoden's Steward, her absence might harm Rohirrim morale (because of suspicions that she might have fled to some place of safety), and if parley was necessary, the enemy leaders might not consider Erkenbrand an appropriate person to negotiate with, but Éowyn's departure did not leave Rohan without leadership, just without royal family leadership

Both Eowyn and Erkenbrand were appointed to separate responsibilities by Theoden. Eowyn didn't appoint anyone to take her place (doing so would not have been in the spirit of sneaking off), but it's not a stretch to assume, in the current military emergency, that Erkenbrand would be challenged should he assume her position.

True.  But Rohan is definitely not left leaderless

Erkenbrand being left in charge does not appear in LotR, so it would appear to be a speculation.

Hunh. Sorry about that.

Updated answer to clarify that the cite is to "Unfinished Tales"

The Gateway also says, "King Théoden named her ruler of Rohan in his and Éomer's absence" on Éowyn's page. As far as I can see. Erkenbrand was not of the house of Eorl, though it may be he assumed command when no one was there to command otherwise, since he already had command of some other forces.

Modified my answer to include more details

The exact quote from UT (a footnote by Tolkien in Appendix (i) to Battle of the Fords of Isen — to para UT 3.05.appendix.01.2.006 in the DTP citation system) justifying the statement about Erkenbrand is slightly subtle to parse; Tolkien Gateway spells it out clearer, but I thought from the above TG quote was from Tolkien, originally.

Here's the quote from UT: "...Erkenbrand was an older man, and the King felt the need of one of dignity and authority to leave behind in command of such forces as could be spared for the defence of Rohan."

If you edit again, could you change "Theodon" to "Théoden"? Too few characters for me to edit.
